# Javascript Fetch Body JSON List

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to make a post request and getting this exception:

```
"unsupported BodyInit type"
```

I think the issue is with the body of the request. `phoneNumbers` takes on the form `phoneNumbers = ["1234567890", "1234567891"]` (i.e. a list of strings). I tried to do JSON.stringify(phoneNumbers) as the body, but that seems to return "[]", even if the list is not empty.

```
 export async function findUsersByPhoneNumbersNotFollowing(userId, phoneNumbers) {
  const reqConfig = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    body: phoneNumbers,
  };


  const response = await authfetch(`${API_URL}/following/recommendations/${userId}`, reqConfig);

  if (response.error) {
    throw new Error(response.error);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? The API endpoint is expecting `List<String>` (using spring framework, and the controller method takes this param in annotated `@RequestBody`)

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a JSON Object instead a plain array:

```js
    const reqConfig = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            paramName: phoneNumbers
        }),
      };
```

Replace `paramName` for the name you are expecting on your API endpoint.

Comment: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: Can you share the code (or ate least part of it) you are using in the endpoint?